# How to get Jenkins working with binaries from COMPOSER_HOME/bin?

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php, build.xml

I'm working on a project and want to use Jenkins for it. The config should be done by a simple `build.xml` with a fiew targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="full-build">
    <property name="phpcs"   value="phpcs"/>
    <property name="phpdox"  value="phpdox"/>
    <target name="full-build" depends="lint, phpdox" description="Performs static analysis, runs the tests, and generates project documentation"/>
    <target name="lint" description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
        <apply executable="php" taskname="lint" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-l" />
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/module/">
                <include name="**/*.php" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/phpunit/tests">
                <include name="**/*.php" />
            </fileset>
        </apply>
    </target>
    <target name="phpdox" description="Generate project documentation using phpDox">
        <exec executable="${phpdox}" dir="${basedir}/ci/phpdox" taskname="phpdox"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The PHP Lint (`php -l`) job works perfectly:

**Console Output**

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\Data\myproject
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/MyAccount/MyProject.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/MyAccount/MyProject.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git.exe config --local credential.username myusername # timeout=10
 > git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git8298647783094567497.credentials\" # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: my.proxy.tld:8080
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/MyAccount/MyProject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 54af2180160f47d518c42f58f56cba175ca2ee39 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 54af2180160f47d518c42f58f56cba175ca2ee39
 > git.exe rev-list 54af2180160f47d518c42f58f56cba175ca2ee39 # timeout=10
[myproject] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: D:\Data\myproject\build.xml

lint:
     [lint] No syntax errors detected in D:\Data\myproject\module\Application\Module.php
     ...
     [lint] No syntax errors detected in D:\Data\myproject\phpunit\tests\Application\DummyTest.php
```

But the executing of PHPDox is failing:

```
phpdox:

BUILD FAILED
D:\Data\myproject\build.xml:18: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpdox" (in directory "D:\Data\myproject\ci\phpdox"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:629)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 24 more

Total time: 8 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The same problem I have with other Composer packages, that are installed [globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) and used from `COMPOSER_HOME/bin` (e.g. PHP_Codesniffer).

I've tried to define the commands in another way (like `<exec executable="cmd"><arg line="/c phpdox ..." /></exec>`), but it's also not working.

The direct executing of the `build.xml` with `ant` works.

The environment variable for the Composer is set correctly -- I can call the tools via the CLI (CMD or GitBash/MinGW). So the problem must have been caused by something else. What can it be?

**How to get Jenkins working with packages installed globally via Composer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linux** (in my case Ubuntu 14.04 Server)

Setting the environment variables in the Jenkins configuration (`Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables`: `name=PATH, value=$PATH:$COMPOSER_HOME/vendor/bin/`) resolved the issue.

[image]

```
$ echo $COMPOSER_HOME
/usr/share/.composer
```

Note, that the `$COMPOSER_HOME` should/may not be set to subfolder of a (`root`) user (e.g. `/root/.composer`), since it can cause [permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463110/how-to-get-jenkins-working-with-binaries-from-a-subfolder-of-the-root-user):

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpcs": error=13, Permission denied

---

**Windows** (in my case Windows Server 2008 r2)

Additionally to setting of the Composer path some further steps were/are needed:

First of I got the error

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpcs": error=2, The system cannot find file specified

On a forum I read, that the target needs to get the path to the executable, like this:

```
<target name="phpcs">
    <exec executable="C:\path\to\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs" taskname="phpcs">
        <arg value="--standard=PSR2" />
        <arg value="--extensions=php" />
        <arg value="--ignore=autoload.php" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/module/" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

But it didn't work and only causes the next error:

> D:\path\to\build.xml:34: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\path\to\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

It's not a Jenkins, but an Ant issue. The cause and the solution are described on the [Ant docu page for `Exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

> **Windows Users**
>
> The `<exec>` task delegates to `Runtime.exec` which in turn apparently
>   calls
>   [::CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dllproc/base/createprocess.asp).
>   It is the latter Win32 function that defines the exact semantics of
>   the call. In particular, if you do not put a file extension on the
>   executable, only ".EXE" files are looked for, not ".COM", ".CMD" or
>   other file types listed in the environment variable PATHEXT. That is
>   only used by the shell.
>
> Note that *.bat* files cannot in general by executed directly. One
>   normally needs to execute the command shell executable `cmd` using the
>   `/c` switch.
>
> ...

So in my case the working target specification looks as follows:

```
<target name="phpcs">
    <exec executable="cmd" taskname="phpcs">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="C:\path\to\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs" />
        <arg value="--standard=PSR2" />
        <arg value="--extensions=php" />
        <arg value="--ignore=autoload.php" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/module/" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

From now the build was passing through. But there was still an issue with `phpcs`:

```
phpcs:
    [phpcs] 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    [phpcs] operable program or batch file.
    [phpcs] Result: 1
```

This is easily fixed by adding `PHP` to the `Path` environment variable in Jenkins (`Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables`):

[image]

That's it. :)