# How to get Jenkins working with binaries from a subfolder of the root user?

Tags: linux, jenkins, ant, permissions, composer-php

In my `build.xml` I defined some jobs, that should be executed by tools, I [installed `global`ly](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/). That means, the binaries are stored in `/root/.composer/vendor/bin/` (I'm working as `root` on my local VM).

I set the `PATH` environment variable in the composer configs (without it the build process was [failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430948/how-to-get-jenkins-working-with-binaries-from-composer-home-bin/36462122)):

[image]

Now the building process is running in permission issues:

```
Started by user anonymous
Running as anonymous
Building in workspace /path/to/myproject
[myproject] $ ant
Buildfile: /path/to/myproject/build.xml

phpcs:

BUILD FAILED
/path/to/myproject/build.xml:30: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpcs": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    ...
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The binaries in `COMPOSER_HOME/bin` are executable for everyone:

```
root@ubuntuvm:~# chmod 777 /root/.composer/vendor/bin/
root@ubuntuvm:~# ls -lia /root/.composer/vendor/bin/
total 8
...
29651 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   42 Feb 17 14:49 phpcs -> ../squizlabs/php_codesniffer/scripts/phpcs
...
```

I've installed the [Authorize Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin) and tried to run the build "as the user who triggered the build", but it didn't help.

[image]

But that seems not to be enough.

**How to give resolve these permissions problems and get Jenkins working with binaries of `global`ly installed Composer packages?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be impossible to execute (Composer) binaries stored in a sub-folder of another (`root`) user from/by Jenkins.

A workaround, that works for me, is to move the `COMPOSER_HOME` to a folder, Jenkins has access to, e.g.:

```
$ mv /root/.composer /usr/share/.composer
$ nano /etc/environment
...
PATH=...
COMPOSER_HOME="/usr/share/.composer"
...
$ nano ~/.profile
...
export PATH=$PATH:$COMPOSER_HOME/vendor/bin
...
```

The `PATH` environment variables needs to be set then in the Jenkins configuration (`Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables`) to `$PATH:$COMPOSER_HOME/vendor/bin/`:

[image: Jankins-settings-PATH]

Answer (score 0):

The executable is not an executable file, but a symlink to another file, and THOSE permissions need to be correct. Did you check that?

Comment: Thank  you for your answer! Yes, just checked this with `chmod -R 777 /root/.composer/vendor/` and `chown -R jenkins /root/.composer/vendor/` at once. Then `cp -s /root/.composer/vendor/bin/* /var/lib/jenkins/bin/`, `chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/bin`, and `chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/bin`. Still "permission denied".

Comment: Note that `chmod` is no tool to do any "checking", it is the brute force hammer to drive the nails identified by the noob administrator.

Comment: What I'd like to say is that instead of CHECKING what the permissions are, you are overwriting everything with the most horrible permission set possible, thus erasing any helpful hints of what was going on. How can this possibly help? I'd suggest `sudo chmod -R 777 /` now if I were evil.

Comment: Sure, `chmod` and `chown` themselves don't check anything. What I meant was, that I checked, whether the issue is caused by the permissions of the executables -- and to do this I simply removed the access restrictions for the user `jenkins` with the sledge hammers `chmod -R 777` and `chown -R`.